# Windows 7 Network Drives Won't Re-Map after Log on

Tags: windows, networking, server, mapping, drive

Basically working in a small network of 35 machines, all running Windows 7 sp1.

Each time a user logs into their machine they have to 'reconnect to the network drive'

There is a group policy setup to automatically do this for them but it does not seem to be working.

I've tried using log on scripts eg... Net Use I:\x.x.x.x\x\x But they won't work either

Setting Local GPO's doesn't seem to work either.

Our drive is an Isilon drive, and we had a permission issue with it a few days back, as in there was permissions setup on the drive that would overwrite any permission changes made on windows. eg, i give user x permissions to all folders on the drive, the folders still appear as read-only.

Basically what i'm wondering is,how can i setup my users so they don't have to constantly re-connect at log in, and, could it be an issue of permissions set on the isilon drive that would cause this?

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: select (Map Network drive)  in computer and click browse. do you see the computers were the drives are shared? if you do then connect to them and tick the reconnect at logon

Comment: is this not the equivalent of doing it on each machine? even after ticking ''reconnect at logon'' it still doesn't reconnect, should have added that to the original post my bad.

Comment: sounds like a network issue -- try this solution (Start > Run > type "gpedit.msc" (without quotes) click ok.
Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon > Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon -
set this to Enable then reboot)

Comment: I Have that enabled, along with a Logon script set up on my account, and a Group policy object, but the drives still need to be re-connected each time and I've no idea why

Comment: login as Administrator and see if that does anything